# Gradle shrinker

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I've run the Gradle shrinker (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#gradle-shrinker) on my project to get rid of unused code but it seems that the shrinker removes too much (causes runtime errors).

build.gradle:

```
   ...
   buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard false
            proguardFiles ('proguard-basic.pro', getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'))
        } 
    }
```

proguard-basic.pro:

```
-dontwarn javax.**
```

There seems to be no equivalent to `usage.txt` (which is what ProGuard generates).

**What can I do for troubleshooting?**

Comment: Note: It seems the shrinker removes some methods that are invoked by a library (EventBus) but even if I add a reference with the proper proguard configuration it doesn't work: http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/proguard/

Comment: I added -keep com.mypackage.** and now it seems to work... (without the proguard config referenced in my first comment)